# Flutter App Icon is not changing the second time

Tags: android, flutter, icons, appicon

I changed the default flutter logo icon with a custom icon, but ended up messing up the alignment of the contents of the icon and wanted to change it again. I tried giving a new image path (path of the modified icon image) in flutter_icons (in pubspec.yaml file), but it didn't work. I even tried changing the default icon files in the res folder (android->app->source->main->res) using an online icon generator, but that didn't work either. Every time I change the icon files, **I will run the commands**: *flutter pub get* and *flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main* to ensure icon changes are made.

**PUBSPEC.YAML file (Old icon):**
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0

flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path: "assets/icon1.png"

**PUBSPEC.YAML file (Icon which I want to use):**
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0

flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path: "assets/icon_foreground.png"

But despite that, the icon I changed the first time is remains unchanged. I want to change my app icon to the modified image. I won't require the steps to change the icon for iOS app, since the app is designed only for Android as of now. I don't know where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, the below suggestions should work.

- Recheck whether that the new icon file assets/icon_foreground.png is
  located in the correct folder in your project directory. It is
  supposed to be in the assets folder at the root level of your
  project.
- Also check that the flutter_icons plugin is installed and added to
  your pubspec.yaml file correctly. Run flutter pub get to ensure that
  all the dependencies are updated.
- Try running `flutter clean` to clean the build artifacts, and then
  run `flutter pub get` and `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` again.
- Make sure that you're running the app on a physical device or
  emulator that has been fully restarted after making the changes to
  the icon.
- Try delete the old icon files from the res folder in your Android
  project, and then run flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  again to regenerate the icon files.
- Also check that you're using the correct icon file name in the
  image_path parameter in your pubspec.yaml file. The file name and
  extension should be correct, and they should match the file name in
  your assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from *@Messi*, below is an example from my pubspec.yaml file in a sample project.
Here, the **icon.png** is located in a directory (**icons/**) inside the **assets** folder.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
```

- Ensure the dependencies are correctly formatted. This can serve as a
  guide.

You can equally create a new project and copy your **libs** and **assets** folder to the new project and the update your **pubspec.yaml** file and re-run then commands.